# Notepad++ how to remove non-UTF-8 characters

Tags: csv, utf-8, notepad++, looker-studio

I've a problem: I'm trying to upload a big csv to google datastudio, it tells me "error: non utf-8 characters found ". 
I'd like to know if is there a way to remove such characters using notepad++ or, at least, how to search for them for replacing by hand.

I tryed with **encoding > convert to utf-8** but doesn't work

EDIT: this is a link to my csv: [CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6vki7lysk4ui2a/Cartel3_a_anonimizzata.csv?dl=0)
this is the error I got from google:

[image]

(I also tryed deleting the line but same error occurs, few lines earlier or few line later)

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very usefull. Edit your question and add sample text and eventualy a hex-dump.

Comment: Open the text file in Windows Notepad, Save As, and set the encoding to UTF-8. If you're not using Windows, find a comparable text editor on your OS that will allow you to do the same.

Comment: I got same issue with notepad

Comment: By now I solved reading original csv to pandas dataframe and writing it back with flag`encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: The fundamental rule of character encodings is to read with the same encoding that was used to write. This applies to the input side of conversions, too. What is the original encoding? If you are converting to UTF-8, then it should be lossless because UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode character set, which is very, very likely to be a superset of whatever your source character set is.

Comment: @TomBlodget I don't know exactly what format I'm coming from, anyway it should be MS Office default (file is an Excel 'semicolon separated' csv). I taught Npp had "auto-sensing" capabilities for encoding because it shows it on bottom-right corner as I open a file.